# sed adding new comment lines in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, cron

I have a script that contains the following line:

```
crontab -l |sed -e 's=\(^.*/usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh$\)=#\1=' | crontab -
```

which will add a '#' to a line in the crontab each time it is executed.

But everytime that line is executed comment lines are added to the crontab like the below:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.2pG8HV installed on Tue May 12 13:02:16 2015)
```

so my crontab after several execution of that script get filled with hundred of comment lines.

how can I make it stop ?

Comment: just delete all the comment lines using `sed '/^#/d' file`

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: there are other comment lines that shouldn't be deleted. Etain I am commenting a crontab line then running other scripts , then uncomenting that line because if it is on during the process it will generate errorrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of crontab, those lines get added at the beginning of the output of `crontab -l`.  Ask `sed` to remove the two first lines then:

```
crontab -l | sed -e '1,2d;s=\(^.*/usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh$\)=#\1=' | crontab -
```